# .zshrcに追記したexportを反映させるために毎回exec zshをする必要がある

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm

macでiterm2を使っています。.zshrcに以下の記述を追記しました。

```
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

`echo $PATH` で確認すると、`exec zsh` をする前には反映されていませんが、した後には反映されています。
itermを開く度に `exec zsh` をしなくてもいいようにしたいです。ご教授お願いいたします。

Comment: `export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH`を`.zshrc`ではなく、`.zlogin`に書くとどうなりますか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

新たにターミナルを開いた場合はその `PATH` の設定は何もしなくても反映されているはずです。 `exec zsh` などは不要です。